# Is Martin Scorsese guilty of no true scotsman?

Tags: logic, fallacies, argumentation, knowledge

Genuine Question: When Martin Scorsese criticised the Marvel Cinematic Universe and directly said that they were theme parks not cinema, was that an example of the no true Scotsman fallacy?

> Blockquote “I don’t see them. I tried, you know? But that’s not cinema, Honestly, the closest I can think of them, as well made as they are, with actors doing the best they can under the circumstances, is theme parks. It isn’t the cinema of human beings trying to convey emotional, psychological experiences to another human being.”

I agree with Martin but I'm just looking to find out whether it's a true example or not so that I can counter a Marvel fans argument that Martin's critique was just an example of the no true scotsman fallacy and therefore not legitimate.

Comment: It’s a minor and frankly pretty valid criticism — these films are usually nestled somewhere between disneyfied military propaganda and outright power fantasies. If you think you have a counter example maybe that could be the basis for analysis here (Nolan’s films were critically acclaimed for instance..)

Comment: I agree with Martin but I was just looking to find out whether it's a true example or not so that I could counter a Marvel fan's argument that Martin's critique was just an example of the no true scotsman fallacy and therefore not legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

If we go down to the philosophical level, what we're dealing with is the issue of *class inclusion*, and it's a thorny subject. Think of it as these three tendencies:

- The tendency to restrict class inclusion on frivolous or tangential grounds, creating an unnecessary bias. 'No True Scotsman' is an informal fallacy (rhetorical ploy) when it restricts the definition of the class 'Scotsman' on the grounds of (say) *prestige*: excluding those who act in ways that make Scotsmen look bad.
- The tendency to expand class inclusion on frivolous or tangential grounds, creating a weak, diluted category. This informal fallacy (rhetorical ploy) doesn't seem to have a commonly used name outside of the ethics-specific term 'moral relativism', but you can imagine an odd parallel construction such as "Everyone who does X is a true Scotsman".
- The ideal of defining class inclusion non-self-referentially, on fixed and objective criteria. This is scientifically coherent, but prosaic and unsatisfying. For instance, we could try to determine who is and is not a 'true' Scotsman using genetic markers, but that seems to entirely miss the point of what it means to be Scottish, which most people will recognize as a set of attitudes in the nexus of psychology and culture, not biology.

When people wrestle with the categorization of moral agents (human beings) and moral agencies (human actions), they usually ignore the last ideal and try to strike a balance between the first two tendencies. Properly used, the 'No True Scotsman' rhetoric is an effort to define what a category *ought* and *ought not* include. Thus a phrase like 'No true Scotsman would wear a [porkpie hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pork_pie_hat)", is more of an encouragement to Scots not to wear such outlandish headgear than an assertion that Scotsmen never do such a thing. If it's used in the latter sense, we get the essence of an informal fallacy, but in the former sense it's merely a normal and unavoidable part of negotiating cultural identity.

Scorsese isn't denying that such 'theme park' movies exist, or that they have merits of their own. He's merely making an 'ought' distinction between *cinema* and *movies*, suggesting that the former need emotional and intellectual depth that the latter often lack. He's essentially outlining for cinema the same distinction we already see and use in writing: you won't generally find Spider Man comics taught in university-level literature courses. Scorsese is outlining standards so that the concept 'cinema' doesn't get overwhelmed by a mass of fun, thrilling, meaningless tripe. It may be a bit snooty, but I expect Scorsese has earned the 'snoot' right. Applying 'No True Scotsman' to this seems more like sour grapes than a functional rhetorical argument.